# Java JNI Error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java

I am trying to run this simple HelloWorld code:

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

}

It compiles just fine but when I try to run it I get the following error:

[image]

I believe I have the most up to date jdk and jre. I'm brand new at java and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `java` version is 1.8 while your `javac` version is 12. Code compiled in later versions of Java cannot be executed by earlier versions of Java. Check your environment variables.

Comment: @slaw so you're saying i need to download the jdk 8?

Comment: You appear to already have both Java 8 (though I can't tell if it's the JDK or just the JRE) and Java 12 installed. What I'm saying is you need to check your environment variables (e.g. `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH`) to make sure they're configured correctly (i.e. everything is pointing to the same version). What does your `PATH` look like?

Comment: @Slaw This is my path:        

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin

Comment: The first entry, `...\Oracle\Java\javapath`, is likely pointing (indirectly) to Java 8 and was likely added when you installed Java 8. This entry doesn't include tools like `javac`, however, so those gets picked up by your last entry: `...\jdk-12.0.1\bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Windows command prompt image you posted, it looks like you are on Windows 7.
The `where` command will show the path of files `java.exe` and `javac.exe`.
Enter the following command at the command prompt:

```
where java.exe
```

On my Windows 10 machine with JDK 12.0.1 installed, the output for the above command is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe
```

And for `javac.exe` ...

```
where javac.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe
```

The folder for `javac.exe` **must** be included in the `PATH` environment variable, otherwise the `where` command would not find it.

The folder for `java.exe` need not be included in `PATH`. You may have defined the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but even that is not required.

In any case, as others have stated, a lower version of the JDK cannot run code that is compiled with a higher version (although the opposite is allowed, i.e. you can compile with a lower version and run it with a higher version).

It would appear that you have more than one JDK (or JRE) version installed. You need to decide which you want to use and modify the `PATH` environment variable so that it includes the desired folder containing file `javac.exe`.

If you don't require several java versions installed, I recommend simply removing all those that you don't require.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, seen an issue like this, it's because of the jdk version you are using to compile your code is not the same with the jdk you are running on your IDE (most likely Eclipse)

You can change the setting in:
Project properties --> Java build path --> Libraries --> select preferred JRE compiler